# Web Part Category List - Appearance of random space

Tags: web-part, categories

Once a web part category is selected the web parts list is displayed having empty
space/gap beneath it eventhough the list is long (with left and right arrow heads enabled).

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Can you elaborate or post a screenshot of the problem?